# Using [Authorize] attribute redirects to the login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, token, authorize, httpresponsemessage

I am using Controller base class on my other controllers, but this specific controller is used to download a file from the server using wpf. I can download the file successfully without any problem if i dont put the [authorize] attribute but putting it redirects me to the login page in which instead of the actual file, the download action returns the actual html code of the login page. Is there any reason you know why is it happening or is ther any solution? i am providing a token but it redirects me anyway to the login page.

```
[Authorize]
public class DownloadController: ApiController
{
    [Route("File")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage File(string serverpath)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var fileDirectory = $@"{HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath}{serverpath}";
        var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileDirectory, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if your token is not expired. Most of the time we pass the expired token and it redirects to the login page.

Comment: Check to see if forms auth cookie is being submitted along with the request for the file. If it isn't, check the cookie's path, domain, and attributes. BTW please see  [OWASP A4](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References).